# Elegant solution to reordering a Laravel Collection (or populate it perfectly from the beginning)?

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have a Laravel Collection with items in it. Assuming the items are in the collection in numerical order.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

If for example I have items 1-15 laid out like the following in the View (the number of rows can change but number of columns will always stay the same):

```
1  4  7  10  13
2  5  8  11  14
3  6  9  12  15
```

*think of each column as a different type of mammal (cats, dogs, birds, etc.)

Is there a way to easily reorder the items like the following within the Collection?

```
1 4 7 10 13 2 5 8 11 14 3 6 9 12 15
```

So in the View it would now look like this:

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
10  11  12
13  14  15
```

*The View that I talk about is for illustrative purposes only. I only require changes to the Collection in the manner stated above. Populating the collection perfectly from the beginning would be the optimal answer but I can't figure out a way to do so.

Comment: Can you add your view code in your question?

Comment: The View code is irrelevant. I'd just like to know how to change the Collection.

Comment: The view code is relevant, reordering the collection is probably not the way you want to solve this.

Comment: No, I say View but I only require changes to the Collection and it was for illustrative purposes only.

Comment: Are you applying an ORDER BY clause when you retrieve the collection from the database?

Comment: Yes, I am applying an ORDER BY. I'm modifying multiple collections and recombining them in a particular fashion.

Comment: How should your example look like with 16 items?

Comment: @lukasgeiter: It will always be a perfect grid.

Comment: If you're down thumbing me please explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is perfect but it works.

*This code assumes `$collection` is the collection you want to reorder*

```
$arrayCollection = array();

$numberOfColumns = 5; // adjust this value to change number of columns
$numberOfRows = $collection->count() / $numberOfColumns

foreach($collection as $index => $model){
    $column = floor($index / $numberOfRows);
    $newIndex = (int)($index % $numberOfRows) * $numberOfColumns + $column;
    $arrayCollection[$newIndex] = $model;
}

ksort($arrayCollection); // sort collection by key

$collection = new Collection($arrayCollection); // make new collection with reordered models
```

Answer (score 1):

Why should you reorder the collection?  Sounds to me you want something like this:

```
@foreach($collection as $item)
    <div class="collection-item">{{ $item->value }}</div>
@endforeach
```

Then apply CSS styles in order to have each of the `collection-item` divs display inline rather than as block elements.

If you truly want a reordered collection, then specify the order you want when you fill the collection:

```
Model::all()->orderBy('field', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question I'm asking.

Comment: On the contrary it does, but only if you're willing to modify your View code.  In Laravel, it makes zero sense to reorder an already filled collection.

Comment: My View is as good as it's going to be. Populating the collection perfectly from the beginning would be the best but I don't see a way to do so. Think of each column as a different type of mammal. How am I going to populate the Collection in the resulting particular fashion that I require?

Comment: _My View is as good as it's going to be_ That sounds dangerously close to the [Ikea Effect](http://technosophos.com/2013/12/10/the-ikea-effect-and-software-development.html)

Comment: My point is, the View is not relevant for this question. And I asked if you had a better suggestion for populating the Collection itself and you didn't have an answer.

Comment: Provide your database schema and I or someone else can. As it is, from what you've provided, modifying the view is the course of action I would take. Provide some more details about your application and we'll see if we can't get your collection loading in the right order for you. How many results are going to be in your query? I sure hope its not very many because of all of the post-processing you're going to have to do.

Comment: I think this solution is perfect.  There is no need to waste cycles to re-order the collection when it will display just fine as it is with some simple css classes placed on each div.  It seems re-ordering the collection would actually make the view *more* complex.

Answer (score 1):

While not discussing whether it makes sense to order the collection or better do it in your SQL query, this is the answer for your generic question (adjust for your specific needs if necessary):

**1 compare function:**

```
/**
 * Sort the array in groups.
 * 
 * @param  mixed    $previous
 * @param  mixed    $next
 * @param  integer  $groups
 * @return bool
 */
function sortInGroups($previous, $next, $groups = 3)
{
    // If equal then return 0
    if ($previous == $next) return 0;

    // Otherwise check the modulus in order to 
    // group the items. However if modulus is zero, 
    // then shift group to the very end of final array.
    $prev = ($previous%$groups) ?: $groups;
    $nxt = ($next%$groups) ?: $groups;

    // If moduli are equal then items are 
    // in the same group so compare the items.
    if ($prev == $nxt) 
    {
        return ($previous < $next) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    // Otherwise compare the moduli in order to group the items.
    return ($prev < $nxt) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

**2 sort the collection by whatever property you want (id for example)**:

```
$collection = SomeModel::take(15)->get(); // or Support\Collection 
$collection->lists('id'); // [1,2,3,4,... 15]

$collection->sort(function ($prev, $next) {
  return sortInGroups($prev->id, $next->id, $cols = 5);
});

$collection->lists('id'); // [1,4,7,10,13,2,5,8,11,14,3,6,9,12,15]
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the OP doesn't want to reorder them by id but by their index in the collection.

Comment: @lukasgeiter well, the question is far from being specific, so we can just guess. However there's seems to be no sense in ordering a collection by the keys (unless it's `Eloquent\Collection` when it's basically `id`), but rather by some of the item's property. The above is, like mentioned, generic solution with `id` as an example, however it can be adjusted to meet pretty much any needs.

Comment: I'd actually like to test out this answer as well. I'm curious which is faster. Could you make the adjustments so it reorders by index?

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Will this still work with irregular ids like `45,53,60,61,62,67...`?

Comment: @lukasgeiter Sure, according to the OP's note: rows may change, columns number remains the same. It uses modulo, so it doesn't matter if the values are sequential or not.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk But exactly because it uses modulo it matters if the id's are sequential or not, doesn't it?

Comment: @lukasgeiter As long as its sole purpose is to rearrange the items, not to group them by anything, this is definitely not the way to go. I would do it before the collection is built (probably in SQL), but again, the question isn't specific. rotaercz - That said, if you just need to sort using keys, instead get the underlying array of items off the collection and use `uksort` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually order by a column.
If these are the id `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15`
Then you can use `order by FIELD(id, 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15);`

Comment: There can be more or less rows. It's not set in stone.

Comment: If the number of element is fixed the generate the order according to the row.

Comment: The number of elements is of a variable length.

Comment: Then you have two way, order it in the view or grub the whole result make the order string and grub it again from db with the desired order